# how to select and diaplay data from jquery date and time picker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am using a j query date and time picker and cannot seem to display the selected data never mind save to a db. I am using php with mysql and am not sure how to get the information. this is the j query date and time picker and the suggested j query to get the date from the picker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#date_picker').dtpicker();
    });
</script>
<script>
PickerHandler.prototype.getDate = function(){
    var $picker = this.$pickerObject;
    var $input = this.$inputObject;
    return getPickedDate($picker);
};
</script>
```

and my html

```
<div class="section section-breadcrumbs"> 
 <div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-12"> 
    <h1>Book An Appointment</h1> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div> 
<div class="section">
 <div class="container"> 
  <center><div id="date_picker">
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){ 
  $('#date_picker').dtpicker(); });
</script> 

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="date_picker"></p>
```

I firstly want to display the returned value to make sure its working before I try and input to db but i cant even get this to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the html code where you are using your `datepicker` example

Comment: <div class="section section-breadcrumbs">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1>Book An Appointment</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
  <center><div id="date_picker"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   $('#date_picker').dtpicker();
  });
    </script>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="date_picker"></p>

Comment: apologies im new to this cant seem to get it displayed as code.

the jquery date time picker is displaying fine, but i am displaying it inline so the code :
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="date_picker"></p>
does not seem to apply for me

Answer (score 0):

here is a couple of examples for the jquery datetime picker . [datepicker1](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) [datepicker2](http://runnable.com/UdTuotHbZoQNAABq/adding-a-date-picker-to-an-input-form-field-using-jquery)

Comment: My JQuery date and time picker is inline and doesnt seem to work with the same methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery datepicker you can load it using the following:
First load necessary javascript and css files for datepicker and then call the datepicker function on the element. (Make sure you include latest jquery)

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better view of the current code:

```
<div class="section section-breadcrumbs">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Book An Appointment</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
    <center><div id="date_picker"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        $('#date_picker').dtpicker();
    });
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="date_picker"></p>

</div></center>
</div>
</div>
```